# Variable with least significance in the most important PCA components

Tags: pca

Suppose we have 3 vars: `v1, v2, v3` and 2 PCs: `PC1, PC2`. `PC1` has a contribution of `0.8` and `PC2` has the same of `0.2`. In the principal coefficient matrix, we have the significance of each var for each PC. Let's say we get: `PC1 -> (v1: 0.46, v2: 0.02, v3: 0.51)` and `PC2 -> (v1: 0.2, v2: -0.12, v3: 0.3)`. Can we say that `v2` is least important for predicting the target variable?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or a textbook?

Comment: Which one is "the target variable"?

Comment: No sir. I created this example on the fly. I believe `v2` is least important, but I want to cross-validate it.

Comment: How is the target variable important?

Comment: It's just not clear: you described v1, v2, v3, and then in the last sentence you suddenly mention "the target variable". Is it one of the v1, v2, v3?

Comment: No, it is not one of v1, v2, v3. And please don't change the title. I kept the earlier one for brevity. Your edited title does not reflect what I want to ask. And if I put it full, the title itself will become like description.

Comment: Okay, apologies for misunderstanding what you want to ask - feel free to change it again, but please make it informative. "Need help on PCA" is not informative & unhelpful & you are likely not to get any answers with such a title.